# Accessing Rvector type in julia DataFrames package

Tags: r, dataframe, julia

I'm trying to do something pretty simple - just save a matrix in R and import it into julia as an array.  It shouldn't be that hard, but I'm struggling to manipulate the `RVector` type which is created when I read data into julia.

Here's a minimal example.  In R, I run the following script:

```
var1 <- matrix( runif(9), 3, 3 )
save( var1, file='~/temp/file1.rda')
```

Then in julia:

```
using DataFrames, DataArrays
x = read_rda("/home/squipbar/temp/file1.rda")
```

I would like to assign `x["var1"]` to an array variable in the julia workspace, let's call it `z`.  One way to do that would to be to initiate `z` as an empty matrix and then fill it with the elements of `x`.

The problem I'm having is that I can't access the elements of `x`.  As `typeof` confirms, the type of `x` is `DataFrames.RVector{Float64,0x0e}`.  This appears not to obey the standard rules of indexing in julia.

```
y = x["var1"] ;
y[1]

ERROR: MethodError: `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::DataFrames.RVector{Float64,0x0e}, ::Int32)
```

The `DataFrames` documentation does not appear to offer any guidance on the `RVector` type.  Does anyone have any ideas where I can find that or some other explanation of how to access the elements?  Even better, is there a simpler way to just pass a matrix from R to julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is `x["var1"].data` what you want?

```
julia> typeof(b)
DataFrames.RVector{Float64,0x0e}

julia> b.data
9-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.543234
 0.0220151
 0.867526
 0.255187
 0.710463
 0.437579
 0.168832
 0.761667
 0.600643
```

or `data(x["var1"])` if there are NAs

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in my opinion would be to just save the matrix as a text file from R and then load it as a text file in Julia.  Is there a reason not to do that here?  For example:

In R:

```
write.table(var1, file = "/path/to/temp.txt", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, quote=FALSE)
```

and then in Julia:

```
using DataFrames
var1 = readtable("/path/to/temp.txt", separator ='\t');
```

This has the added advantage that it will be easy for you to view the file in a standard text editor if you want to inspect it or a piece of it, it will be easy to manipulate it with another program like python, easy to share it with other people, etc.

Comment: Sure.  This is a workaround.  And it does have the other advantages that you suggest.  But really the problem I want to use this for is not one where there is just one variable, but many vectors and matrices that come from some statistical analysis in R.  These are inputs for some computationally intensive work in julia.  The approach you suggest would mean having many text files and looping through the `readtable` commands to load them up.  It would be much more elegant if I could save the many R objects to a single file and then load them to a dictionary in julia with one line.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some of the tests in the source docs [here](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/test/RDA.jl) it looks like the following can work: if you use your code exactly as you've written, but convert your matrix in R to a data frame before saving, then it convert the result to a DataFrame after bringing it into Julia.  Specifically, then

In R:

```
var1 <- data.frame(matrix( runif(9), 3, 3 ))
save( var1, file='/path/to/file1.rda')
```

and then in Julia:

```
using DataFrames, DataArrays
x = read_rda("/path/to/file1.rda")
y = DataFrame(x["var1"])
```